# How to plot the Error and the Tree size of a Random Forest

Tags: python, plot, random-forest

I created a RandomForestRegressor with 100 Trees and now I want to check, if the RandomForest is overfitted. Therefore I want to plot the Error on the y-axis and the Tree size (1,...100, x-axis). But I could not find the answer how I get the prediction of each Tree. Now I have just the error for each datapoint. I searched for days now and I hope somebody could help me to find the answer. Thank you very much!

```
forest_model = RandomForestRegressor
(estimators=100,
min_sample_split=2,
min_sample_leaf_5,
random_state=42)

forest_model.fit(X_train_v1, y_train_v2)
```

[image]

I want something like this plot just for a RandomForestRegressor

Comment: Can you show us some minimalistic code? That way it is easier to understand where you are standing and to give a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank fpr the tipp :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to plot a learning curve for both the training and testing set with different tree sizes. This is the minimal code to do it. Then you check for overfitting by comparing the two lines.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

train_results = []
test_results = []
list_nb_trees = [5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60, 80, 100]

for nb_trees in list_nb_trees:
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=nb_trees)
    rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    train_results.append(mean_squared_error(y_train, rf.predict(X_train)))
    test_results.append(mean_squared_error(y_test, rf.predict(X_test)))

line1, = plt.plot(list_nb_trees, train_results, color="r", label="Training Score")
line2, = plt.plot(list_nb_trees, test_results, color="g", label="Testing Score")

plt.legend(handler_map={line1: HandlerLine2D(numpoints=2)})
plt.ylabel('MSE')
plt.xlabel('n_estimators')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How I will now if the RandomForestRegressor is overfitted? My lines have a deviation of about 0.0005 and they are almost parallel

Comment: It is extremely unlikely for Random Forest to overfit if the dataset is big enough. Overfitting is linked with reduction of bias, while random forests are almost exclusively based on variance reduction :) But in general, you will be overfitting if your test-error curve starts going back up when the train one keeps decreasing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. It is possible that this code shows just the last RF and not all of them?